# Visio tooltip display in SharePoint 2013 webpart

Tags: web-part, visio

Tooltips works fine in the Visio drawing. Once saved as `vdw` file and embedded in a Visio WebAccess Webpart in SharePoint 2013, the tooltips won't display by mouse-over Action.

Is there any solution?